# Garbage collector : data structure of the object graph

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, garbage-collection

I read many resources on garbage collecting where they explained different algorithm. However, I didn't find any explaining the representation of the graph object.

My idea is quite simple : an oriented graph where vertex represent allocated memory block (on heap) and the edges the owner relationship. Example : Consider 2 memory blocks m1 and m2, if m1 contains reference to a block inside m2 then add an edge (m1, m2). These edges are weighted with the number of references to m2 that m1 contains (here just 1). Finally I've got a "virtual" memory vertex representing the stack, call it M0. Every Mi reachable from M0 mustn't be garbage collected.

Okay, now consider you want to add a memory block to the graph. If we keep the vertices inside a set, then the complexity of adding a memory block should be of O(log(n)).
First question : Can we do better ?

Idem for deleting.

Now, I'm asked to use this algorithm with a reference counting mechanism in C++ (shared_ptr). Firstly, is the reference counter isn't redundant with the in-degree of a vertex ?

Secondly, the key idea is to use the best of the reference counter (O(1) deleting/adding) with the best of the garbage collector algorithm (cleaning reference cycles), but is the overhead of adding/deleting each node in the object graph isn't a bit non-efficient ?

What are the complexities of adding/removing in known garbage collector (java / C# / …) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... your premise is off. Known garbage collectors don't maintain much state actually, at most a couple *bits* per object and some structure but that's it. Instead, they build up some state at each collection pass and let it die at the end of the pass. This way, they need little (to no) instrumentation of the ownership relationships.

Comment: Imagine implementing a garbage in C++, you can't query the stack neither the heap to ask the addresses of the objects actually used. But maybe, it's a good idea to have a linked list (O(1) insertion/removal) and to build the graph only when needed.

Comment: @PierreT.: Actually, if you look at the Boehm Garbage Collector you will realize it does scan the stack/heap, and just treats any possible pointer-sized, pointer-aligned set of bytes as a possible pointer (does not work well in 32-bits). In C++11, some facilities were even introduced to support this approach, if you look at the [`<memory>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) header, you'll see things like `std::declare_no_pointers` to declare that an area of memory does not contain pointers (for example)...

Comment: ... You can also look at [LLVM intrinsics](http://llvm.org/docs/GarbageCollection.html), such as `llvm.gcroot`.

Comment: However, I read that the conservative garbage collectors can miss-scan addresses. I also read that there isn't any portable ways to scan the heap/stack in C/C++.

Comment: @PierreT. That's true. Scanning the stack is highly platform-specific, and without a lot of metadata and restrictions (generally not present in C and C++) you also can't reliably identify pointers, so you have to assume that everything that might be a pointer from the raw bytes actually is a pointer. This may, for example accidentally keep alive objects. Also, if the code does hacks like `xor`ing pointers (cf. XOR Linked list), the GC doesn't stand a chance. Scanning the raw memory is also hard, though AFAIK not quite as platform-specific.

Comment: @PierreT.: this is why the `gcroot` annotation in LLVM allows you to tag interesting (root) objects: so that you can abstract away the platform.